# Why is my attribute table only showing one row of values?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I have 68280 features in my QGIS layer which I have loaded from SQL, however when I open my attributes table it only shows 1 'filtered' row. Why? The rest of the values are not showing.

Comment: Do u see 68280 objects in the map ?

Comment: No it is not plot into the map yet. I am intending to save it as a excel file and plot using delimited text layer to plot my X/Y axis. On the ribbon of the attributes table is 'Features total: 68280, filtered: 1, selected: 0'

Comment: Solved it - The primary key has to be specifically be an ID count. I placed it as postcodes (to be fair it was all different). I guess the system just doesn't like that.